# SharePoint Online Office Map

Tags: windows, sharepoint

I'm setting up an assets list in SharePoint Online with all the information for Computers, Monitors, Phones, and other things.  What I would like to do is add a Room number that links to the office floor plan focused and/or zoomed in on the location.  Is something like this even possible?  Any plugins that would allow for this?

Or is there a better place to ask this?

Comment: This actually sounds pretty darned useful.